# How to distribute this architecture?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb, wildfly, load-balancing

In many examples  [exampleLink](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2011/02/07/adding-cdi-to-an-existing-java-ee-6-application/)

We see that to operate CRUD operations on an X entity.

The components involved are :

X : an entity describing an X (ex : for an entity Book : title, ISBN number, 
 price…)

XService : interface Local

XServiceImpl: a stateless EJB to have transactions for persisting, updating, removing, finding from a database

XClientService : a client Rest interface service that gives a RESTful interface to the EJB

XClientServiceImpl: a Rest implementation of the client interface service that gives a RESTful interface to the EJB

which could be translated to code like below :

```
import javax.ejb.Local;
// This an Basic interface service example for operating on X.
@Local
public interface XService {

}


// This is an Basic service implementation example for operating on X.
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless 
public class XServiceImpl implements XService
{

}



import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Client service with CRUD operations for working with Xs.
 */
public interface XClientService {

  ... create(...);
  ... get(...);
  ... update(...);
  ... delete(...);  
}



import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
/**
 * Client service implementation with CRUD operations for working with Xs.
 */
@Path("/X")
public class XClientServiceImpl implements XClientService
{
  //@Inject is used to inject an stateless EJB interface into the Rest web service 
  @Inject
  private XService xService;

    @GET
    @Produces(JSON)
    @Override
    public Response get() {


        return Response.ok().entity(x).build();

    }
}
```

This way of doing things remains ambiguous for me:

Q1- Why are we forced to go through the Rest Api before contacting the EJB? why not go directly to the EJB?
(Is it the need that different applications could consume that Rest API i.e to ensure that application to run on a variety of platforms. IOS, Android, Windows etc...?)

Q2- On the other hand, knowing that Wildfly has an in-built webserver, and assuming that our Front-End is AngulaJS then is the Rest-Api residing in this
case in the web-container (Scenario 1) or in ejb-container (Scenario 2)? 
(see pictures below)

Scenario 1:
[image]

Or Scenario 2:
[image]

On the other hand, Imagine that we followed the same strategy on a Maven multi-project-layout with several modules and concrete wrapper projects for the jars, ejb, ear and war.  as illustrated below

## For a module X1

- app-modules-X1-client
- app-modules-X1-client-impl
- app-modules-X1-service
- app-modules-X1-service-impl

  ```
  ├── pom.xml
  ├── src
  │   └── main
  │       ├── java
  │       │   └── com
  │       │       └── production
  │       │           └── package
  │       │               └── app
  │       │                   └── X1
  │       │                       ├── client
  │       │                       │   └── impl
  │       │                       └── service
  │       │                           └── impl
  │       └── resources (optional)
  └── target
  ```

  ...........................

## For a module Xn

- app-modules-Xn-client
- app-modules-Xn-client-impl
- app-modules-Xn-service
- app-modules-Xn-service-impl

  ```
  ├── pom.xml
  ├── src
  │   └── main
  │       ├── java
  │       │   └── com
  │       │       └── production
  │       │           └── package
  │       │               └── app
  │       │                   └── Xn
  │       │                       ├── client
  │       │                       │   └── impl
  │       │                       └── service
  │       │                           └── impl
  │       └── resources (optional)
  └── target
  ```

Maven will execute in the root project creates all sub projects and artifacts. and for Deployment, we create via maven the 'ear' . 
The content of the resulting ear file i.e resulting-ear.ear would have a content like the one illustrated below :

```
    └── resulting-ear.ear
        ├── META-INF
        │    ├── maven 
        │    │   ├──com.production.package.app
        │    │      ├──pom.properties
        │    │      ├──pom.xml
        │    ├── application.xml 
        │    └── MANIFEST.MF 
        ├─────── App-war.war
                ├── css
                │    ├── bootstrap <-- bootstrap framework
                │    ├── fonts <- bootstrap fonts
                │    └── ... <- application css files
                ├── images
                │    ├── ... <- application image files
                ├── js
                │    ├── controllers <- application controllers
                │    ├── directives <- application directives
                │    ├── services <- application services used across the application *-service.js
                │    ├── external <- external js libraries
                │    └── ... <- application js and routes
                ├── templates
                │    └── ... <- application wide templates
                ├── WEB-INF
                │   └── web.xml
                │   └── lib
                │   │     ├── dependecie1.jar <- application dependencie1
                │   │     ├── dependecieN.jar <- application dependencieN
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X1-client.jar
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X...-client.jar
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-Xn-client.jar
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X1-client-impl.jar
                │   │     └── * app-modules-X...-client-impl.jar
                │   │     └── * app-modules-Xn-client-impl.jar
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X1-service.jar
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X...-service.jar
                │   │     └── * app-modules-Xn-service.jar          
                │   │     ├── * app-modules-X1-service-impl.jar
                │   │     └── * app-modules-X...-service-impl.jar
                │   │     └── * app-modules-Xn-service-impl.jar
                │   │
                │   └── classes 
                │   └── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
                └── index.html <- root single page application
```

Q3- How, in that case, The best way to distribute and scale horizontally, over 
    many nodes, the ear file ? (knowing that all the session beans are 
    stateless)?

The client application (which is the web application HTML5 files AngularJS files css .js files img etc) and the Rest-Api accessing the session beans can be run within the same instance of an application server (collocated) or from different instances running on the same machine. They can also be run on physically separate machines that have an instance of an application server like below :

[image]

Q4- Did we need, in that case, to more coding to handle the loadbalancing and 
    failover or it's only a matter of configuration of app servers like 
    Wildfly and Hardware unities ?

If my understanding is correct:

If we want to distribute and scale horizontally, over many nodes, the ear files (like they are right now, i.e without any change operated on the code, i.e by just editing configuration file: i.e by passing from standalone-full.xml to standalone-full-ha.xml) :

Q5- is the AngularJS UI wouldn't be in that case also replicated on each node?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should elaborate a little bit more on how you plan to build the Wildfly cluster. Did you check [Wildfly High Availability Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/High+Availability+Guide)? How is deployment done when you  "distribute the application to many nodes"? Are you using the domain mode, server-groups, clustered EJBs, ...?

Comment: Thank you Frito I updated my question based on your hints,

Answer (score 0):

```
Q1- Why are we forced to go through the Rest Api before contacting the EJB? 
    why not go directly to the EJB?
```

Answer: By taking advantage of the http protocle, we ensure that application run on a variety of platforms 
        different applications could consume that Rest API over http : 
        IOS, Android, Windows, DesktopApp(embedding an apache HttpClient and json(to convert pojo to json and back from json to pojo)).

If we want to go directly to the EJB without using http:

```
     - The first option is to have a jvm on the client, means an java application that could reach
       the ejb directly by using RMI.

     - The second option is to have a not jvm app on the client, means a not java application,e.g dot.net app that could reach
       the ejb directly by using RMI-IIOP

     - The third option is to use http protocle from client requests to reach a between media on the webcontainer, This between media        
       could be servlet jsp  and webcontainer who knows very well(by default) how to handle the contact with ejbs embedded on the ejbcontainer via RMI.
    so as you can see the third option using servlet or jsp, this way of doing has now been overtaken by the use of the new standard Rest API as mediate 
    in between.
```

Q2- On the other hand, knowing that Wildfly has an in-built webserver, and assuming that 
        our Front-End is AngulaJS then is the Rest-Api residing in this case in the web-container 
        (Scenario 1) or 
        in ejb-container (Scenario 2)? 
        (see pictures below)

```
Answer: in webContainer (Scenario 1) as you can deduce from the first answer.
```

Q3- How, in that case, The best way to distribute and scale horizontally, 
    over many nodes, the ear file ? (knowing that all the session beans are stateless)?

```
Answer: 
        theoretically,you should have to get everything out of your front-end from the wildfly container 
        and leave in wildfly container only Rest-api in its webcontainer and the beans in ejbcontainer. 
        Your front-end should contact clustered wildfly containers only via http/json, 
        i.e your Front-end should act as a RestClient for the clustered Rest-api wildfly containers.
```

easy thing for stateless ejbs case but it is not easy task, in the case of for statefull ejbs it's difficult to achieve in that case. 
            because it is necessary to distribute stateful transactions and 
            the use of distributed memory such as Ehecache, Hazelcast, Infinispan 
            and the management of XA transactions via narayana transaction manager.

Q4- Did we need, in that case, to more coding to handle the loadbalancing and failover 
    or it's only a matter of configuration of app servers like Wildfly and Hardware unities ?

```
Answer: both
```

Q5- is the AngularJS UI wouldn't be in that case also replicated on each node?

```
in the figure that you imagined yes in this case you will repeat the front end on each node, 
but in reality it does not happen in this way.
we deduce from the previous answer that the front-end AngularJs should not be replicated 
but it will be aggregation of microservices having each microservice its own clustering mechanism. 
but to be at the height of this hard task you must use architecture that can easily help 
you to perform scaling such as CQRS pattern embeded for each microservice 
called by your application AngularJS. AngularJS reach the clustered wildflys by using http/json.
```